# YAML regex_replace single quote

Tags: regex, yaml, regexp-replace

I have tried escaping single quote with `\` or `\\` or `\\\` and `''`

Example string:

```
(user1@email.com,'active', 'monthly')
```

I have tried the following regex, I'm able to remove starting`(` and ending `)` but its not removing single quotes

```
regex_replace('\\(|\\)|'' ', '')
```

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `replace` instead of `regex_replace`

```
replace(\"'\",'')
```